# How to use two integers as a key

Tags: javascript, collections, key

I have a memoization problem. There is a value calculated between two objects and I want to store it, such that I can pass in the two number id's from the objects to get the value regardless of the order that I pass in the id's.

I could just store it under both of the id's, or check for both id's, but I was wondering out of curiosity if there was a more efficient solution.

Examples:

Check for both id's:

```
var storedValues = {};
function generateValue(a, b)
{
    if (storedValues[a.id][b.id])
        return storedValues[a.id][b.id];
    else if (storedValues[b.id][a.id])
        return storedValues[b.id][a.id];
    else
        // Generate value, store it under a.id and return it
}
```

Store it under both id's:

```
var storedValues = {};
function generateValue(a, b)
{
    if (storedValues[a.id][b.id])
        return storedValues[a.id][b.id];
    else
        // Generate value, store it under a.id and b.id and return it
}
```

How can I generate a unique map key from two numbers, so I can retrieve the value with those two numbers regardless of the order that I pass them in?

I'm using JavaScript btw.

Comment: please add some data to illustrate the problem. maybe you could add some code you tried as well.

Comment: I have edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to that, first of all, you can just create a single key for the objectkey e.g.: `'11_12'`

```
var storedValues= {};
var id1  = 11;
var id2  = 12;
var calculatedvalue = id1  * id2;
var objectkey = id1+'_'+id2;
storedValues[objectkey] = calculatedvalue;
```

it is also possible to use nested object:

```
var storedValues= {};
var id1  = 11;
var id2  = 12;
var calculatedvalue = id1  * id2;
if (storedValues[id1] == null ){
    storedValues[id1] = {};
}
storedValues[id1][id2] = calculatedvalue;
```

More over your ids are always integer you can use Arrays

```
var storedValuesArr = [];
var id1  = 11;
var id2  = 12;
var calculatedvalue = id1  * id2;
if (!Array.isArray(storedValuesArr[id1])){
    storedValuesArr[id1] = [];
}
storedValuesArr[id1][id2] = calculatedvalue;
```

and in order to return the values regardless of the order:

```
function generateValue(a, b)
{
    if (storedValues[a.id] != null && storedValues[a.id][b.id] !== null)
        return storedValues[a.id][b.id]
    else if (storedValues[b.id] != null && storedValues[b.id][a.id] !== null)
        return storedValues[b.id][a.id];
    else
        // Generate value, store it under a.id and return it
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question. The first one only returns the value if you pass the objects in the function in the correct order otherwise it stores it again in the other order. I am already using a nested collection, I corrected my examples.

Comment: Ah so, than it is only possible by checking both combinations

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the keys for setting the value and for getting the value.

```js
function getValue(object, key0, key1) {
    return [key0, key1]
        .sort((a, b) => a - b)
        .reduce((o, k) => (o || {})[k], object);
}

function setValue(object, key0, key1, value) {
    var keys = [key0, key1].sort((a, b) => a - b),
        last = keys.pop();
    object[keys[0]] = object[keys[0]] || {};
    object[keys[0]][last] = value;
}

var object = {};

setValue(object, 3, 7, 42);
console.log(getValue(object, 3, 7));
console.log(getValue(object, 7, 3));
console.log(object);
```

Different approach by using the keys a given.

```js
function getValue(object, key0, key1) {
    return key0 in object ? object[key0][key1] : object[key1][key0];
}

function setValue(object, key0, key1, value) {
    object[key0] = object[key0] || {};
    object[key0][key1] = value;
}

var object = {};

setValue(object, 3, 7, 42);
console.log(getValue(object, 3, 7));
console.log(getValue(object, 7, 3));
console.log(object);
```

Comment: The obvious solution is to check for both id's. I'm not reluctant to do so, I was just looking for a more efficient method. I highly doubt this is more efficient.